# Connect php to mysql safely using encrypted password

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, passwords, hardcoded

I am a php beginner and was wondering what it the best way to connect to mysql database safely.

To start, I know that I need to save the password in a config file, but should I save it encrypted or plain?

Should the password passed to mysql_connect be plain?

If so, should I encrypt the password in config file and then decrypt it? Is the decryption possible?

Comment: Just try to use mysqli because mysql is deprecated. Try to look at this tutorials http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: You usually dont encrypt the password. Would also recommend using PDO

Comment: If your php script can decrypt it, a hacker with access to your server can as well, so there is really no point in encrypting it.

Comment: Then how to save the password in this case?

Comment: In a config file somewhere outside of the web-root.

Answer (score 0):

This is why DB encryption is really not secure. At a minimum it must be in RAM memory to access the encrypted data.

If the DB encryption is stored on the server in any manner an attacker who gains admin access will get the key.

Secure all servers with 2-factor authentication.

The next step up is to move the DB to a server that is not connected to the Internet on a very secure and limited server with rate limiting/exception logging the the Internet facing server connects to.

Additionally the key can be secured at rest in an HSM.

It all depends on the security requirements. First you need to define the threat model and then the security requirements, nothing is fully secure so there is a design tradeoff.